# Combine regex for mobile number validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Scenario: Front end validation - Mobile number Must be numeric, must start with '02', have at least 8? numeric characters, limited to 13? numeric characters

Examples:

MSISDN  errorMessage
021123  Please enter a valid Vodafone mobile number,
091234567   Please enter a valid Vodafone mobile number,
02112345678910  Please enter a valid Vodafone mobile number,
abcdefghijkl    Please enter a valid Vodafone mobile number,
021$123456  Please enter a valid Vodafone mobile number

Also, the format for the number should be 021 055555 when I enter the number in the input field. space after the first three numbers.

can anyone help me form a regex for such kind of example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something of this sort would help

```
input.match(/^02[0-9]{6,11}$/)
```

Explanation: input is obviously the input. `^` ensures that this is where the string to be matched begins. `[0-9]` means the subsequent characters must be between 0 and 9, and `{6-11}` means that these characters can be repeated between 6 and 11 times. `$` at the end indicates that this is where the string must end.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this regex would perform the match you need:

```js
const numbers = [
  "023 45678901",
  "023 456789012",
  "023 4567890123",
  "033 45678901",
  "013 45678901",
  "013 45",
  "013 45678901234567",
]

const numberIsValid = number => !!number.match(/02\d\s\d{5,10}/)

console.dir(numbers.map(numberIsValid))
```

Here is what each part of the regex is doing:

`02` matches the characters 02 literally (case sensitive)

`\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

`\d{5,10}` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`{5,10}` Quantifier — Matches between 5 and 10 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)